# Define a date string using a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to produce a date in the form m/d/y by putting in 3 numbers and defining the string "date" using the dictionary:

```
{"m":<number>,"d":<number>,"y":<number>}
```

For example, I want to put in 1,5,2000 and have python return "1/5/2000"
I do not want to use datetime or separate variables.

```
def date_string(date):
```

Comment: Use `d = {"m":1,"d":5,"y":2000}`
`print("/".join(map(str, list(d.values()))))`

Comment: @eyllanesc: Never depend on a dictionary's order.

Comment: @zondo unless you're in Python3.6+?

Comment: @zondo
`print("/".join(map(str, [d[key] for key in ("m", "d", "y")])))` :)

Comment: Nowhere in the question does it specify a Python version that recent. It's such a common mistake to assume the order remains that I think it's very important to mention it works only since 3.6.

Comment: @Alex Your question and comments implies the object you are trying to format is not a dict. Which contradicts the example in your question. I'm guessing that when you say "string date" you really mean something like a `datetime` object which just happens to have the string representation you expect when used in a string context.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this has been said in the comments, let me make it a formal answer:

```
def date_string (date): # where date is a dict
    return str (date ["m"]) + "/" + str (date ["d"]) + "/" + str (date ["y"])
```

Or, if you want to be cool:

```
date_string = lambda date: "/".join (map (str, [date [key] for key in ("m", "d", "y")]))
```

(Credits to @eyllanesc for that last one)

Comment: I keep getting the error message "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Can you try to cram your code in a comment? Also, I'm assuming `date` is a dict like you said